# Alter layout in AsyncTask from a different AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-asynctask, lazy-loading

I want to do the following. I want to display a list with information and images. These images take a while to load, so I thought I would do it differently. I would use two AsyncTasks. The first creates all the layouts and fills it with data except the images. The second one just inserts the images into the layout. The problem I'm encountering is, that I don't know how this would be possible?

In my first AsyncTask, I'm creating TableLayouts and rows and then fill them with data

This is just a bit of my code to understand it a bit how I create the layout

Here I create firstly the TableLayouts and TableRows

```
tableLayout [i] = new TableLayout   (getActivity());
headingRow  [i] = new TableRow      (getActivity());
headlineRow [i] = new TableRow      (getActivity());
imageDescRow[i] = new TableRow      (getActivity());
spaceView   [i] = new LinearLayout  (getActivity());
```

Then I fill TextViews with data

```
headline    [i].setText( headlineArr    [i] );
date        [i].setText( realDate           );
source      [i].setText( sourceArr      [i] );
description [i].setText( descriptionArr [i] );
```

Then I add the TextViews to the Tables and the Tables to the Layout. The code is of course much bigger and does way more than what I'm just doing. And it works without any problems. The only problem still encountering is that Image Loading takes too long to load and I don't want to stop the User from using my app just because Images are loading.

What would be the best way to do that? I thought I would just create another AsyncTask in the onPostExecute method from the current asynctask and pass the URLs of the Images as a parameter. And then in the doInBackgroundMethod I would add the images. But how do I use a layout from another AsyncTask in the new AsyncTask? And wouldn't it destroy the whole layout if I would leave the images empty?

What would be the best way to do such a lazy load?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem here. `AsyncTask`'s `onPosExecute` method runs on `UIThread` and you can reach any ui component there. To summarize, your flow must be sth like this:

1. Load data with an `AsyncTask` let me name it `NoImageAsyncTask`. This
   task will do long operation on its `doInBackground` method which runs
   on a seperate thread than `UIThread`.
2. When `NoImageAsyncTask` finished, its `onPosExecute` method will be
   invoked. Since `onPostExecute` method runs on `UIThread`, you can now
   update your UI wit this data.
3. At `onPostExecute` method, start n(n is the count of imageUrls you
   have from the data you got) new `AsyncTasks` (let me name it
   `ImageAsyncTask`). These `ImageAsyncTasks`' should download images on
   their `doInBackground` method. After download completed `onPostExecute`
   will be triggered and you get the image now. You can update your UI
   on `onPostExecute` method because it runs on `UIThread`.

BTW I recommend you to use a library for image loading purpose. I'm currently using [Shutterbug](https://github.com/applidium/Shutterbug) for this.

Comment: The problem I see is, that if I initialize the image in the first AsyncTask and add it to the layout I can't use the same ImageView in the second AsyncTask. And this means, that I also can't use the TableRows from the first Layout on my new secondary AsyncTask

Comment: You can reach/use any views on the content from AsyncTask's methods which runs on UIThread (onPreExecute, onPostExecute or onProgressUpdate). You should check your code again. Maybe you are not adding your ImageView from the first AsynTask and you are getting a NPE at second AsyncTask.